# Using a date to find out the number of data entry in time series vector

Tags: r, date, time-series, extract

I am currently working with time series data. Having converted the data using the time series function and indicating the correct starting point and frequency, I wondered if it is possible to do operations using a date as indicator for referring to a specific data entry. More specifically, if I have a quarterly series from 1994Q1 to 2007Q2 I wondered if I can access a range of data entries using something like

I hope the following code helps to understand my problem:

```
# Assuming that full.data is the data sample
full.data <- ts(seq(1:56),start=c(1994,1),frequency = 4)

# I would like to extract specific data entries using dates. Of course,
# the example below does not work but I wondered if something similar like this would be possible:
data.short <- data.full["1995Q1" : "2005Q2"]
```

I would really appreciate any help or idea, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `window()` function which is apparently made for this scenario:

```
data.short <- window(full.data, start = c(1995, 1), end = c(2005, 2))
```

See `?window` for further information.

Comment: I thank you so much! That is exactly what I was searching for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Convert to xts and then use the syntax shown.  You can omit the conversion back if an xts object is ok:

```
library(xts)

xx <- as.xts(full.data)
as.ts(xx["1995-1/2005-2"])
```

giving:

```
   Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1     5    6    7    8
2     9   10   11   12
3    13   14   15   16
4    17   18   19   20
5    21   22   23   24
6    25   26   27   28
7    29   30   31   32
8    33   34   35   36
9    37   38   39   40
10   41   42   43   44
11   45
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is also a very reasonable solution to the problem. I appreciate your contribution!